Why Postgres DB sorts, even though I have an index?
This is the table schema:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events_table
(
      id                    UUID NOT NULL,
      comp_id              INT8 NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

We have the following index:
CREATE INDEX events_idx ON events_table (comp_id);

And this is the query:
SELECT 
    table_name.id,
    table_name.comp_id,
FROM 
    schema_name.table_name
WHERE 
    (table_name.comp_id in Array[?])

Why is the DB sorting in the first place:
 Gather Merge  (cost=116700.30..129758.08 rows=111916 width=122) (actual time=357.017..512.239 rows=295813 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=115700.28..115840.17 rows=55958 width=122) (actual time=345.202..364.049 rows=98604 loops=3)
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 13760kB
         ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on  (cost=6311.95..107650.92 rows=55958 width=122) (actual time=51.027..280.405 rows=98604 loops=3)
              
 Planning Time: 0.445 ms
 Execution Time: 528.740 ms
(16 rows)

Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on first?
should not sort, since the index is maintaining the sort order.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html says "The exact rule is that equality constraints on leading columns, plus any inequality constraints on the first column that does not have an equality constraint, will be used to limit the portion of the index that is scanned.". If I understand this correctly, your IN condition breaks this rule, and query planner ignores the index. Especially with such big IN condition, the sequential scan (after sorting) will likely be more efficient.

You can try creating a temporary table (on the fly), inserting all those employe_id there and use JOIN instead of IN. You can also try putting a separate index on employe_id and remove it from the composite. Btw indexing a timestamp is rarely a good idea (too many entries), you can try putting an index on date part only. This will likely reduce index size, might help the planner.

PostgreSQL is using the index idx_balance_state_event_filtering, not events_idx.

The reason an explicit sort is needed is because the index scan does not necessarily return the rows in sorted order. The cause is the IN condition.
If you have a three-column index on (a, b, c), the following query does not need an explicit sort, because the index scan returns the rows in sorted order:
SELECT ... WHERE a = 42 AND b = 'something' ORDER BY c

But this query will need an explicit sort:
SELECT ... WHERE a 0 42 AND b IN ('something', 'other') ORDER BY c


The rows would be returned by the index only piecewise ordered, that is, ordered separately for each chunk derived from the same employee_id.  This is not the same thing as a total ordering your query specified.
PostgreSQL could get each sorted piece and then interleave them together with something like a "Merge Append", but no one has bothered to implement this. It isn't clear how this would even be implemented as doing the merge within the index scan node would be weird, while getting the boundaries up into some separate merge node would be tricky.
It is hard to believe this matters, as the sort takes up a minority of the total time and that total time is pretty fast to start with given the number of rows being returned.  Getting rid of the sort might even make it slower, as then you would not get the IO benefit that you might be getting from sequential-read-like property of the bitmap and the parallelization might also be more difficult.
You could get a literal Merge Append mode by writing the query as a UNION ALL of a bunch of subqueries, once for each value in the IN-list.  You would need to specify the ORDER BY on each subquery as well as on the entire UNION ALL in order to get the desired behavior.  This would be rather awkward to write, and while the performance improvement can be spectacular in certain situations it is hard to see how your query is one of those situations.
